# How to find the differential $y(x)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

We have 
$$(cosx - xsinx + y^2)dx + (2xy)dy = 0 $$
with $y(π)=1$ and $y(x)=y$.

How do we find the $y(x)$?

Comment: I would say - it is an exact differential equations --> the solution is simple (the specified differential equation is a total differential of search function).

Comment: Could you maybe write this equation in a more understandable way? I mean with it having y' inside.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_differential

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$(cosx - xsinx + y^2)dx + (2xy)dy = 0 \implies d (x\cos x + xy^2)=0 \implies  x\cos x + xy^2=c$$
As per given initial condition, the required solution is
$$x\cos x + xy^2=0$$
Hope this helps.

Comment: Isn't it d(xcosx+2xy^2)=0 ?

Comment: @Irene No. It is as I have written.

Answer (score 0):

Write

$$(\cos x-x\sin x)dx+(y^2dx+2xydy)=d(x\cos x)+d(xy^2)=d(x\cos x+xy^2)$$ and the solution is

$$x\cos x+xy^2=C=\pi\cos\pi+\pi1^2=0.$$